# Importing other files when using python setuptools entry_points - no module named

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I am not familiar with setuptools so I hope this is a simple mistake (but couldn't find anything related).

I have this in my setup.py

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts':[
        'filea=autostart.filea:main'
    ]
}
```

And my autostart.filea has

```
from fileb import ClassName
```

(filea and fileb are both inside autostart)

This works file when I run

```
python autostart/filea.py
```

but not when I run the

```
filea
```

binary directly.

In this case I get

```
packages/autostart/filea.py", line 15, in <module>
    from fileb import ClassName
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fileb'
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Use only absolute imports. Meaning your imports should start with the top-level package which is `autostart` in your case. So for example in `autostart/filea.py` there should be `from autostart.fileb import ClassName`. -- And also very important, `autostart/filea.py` is considered a module instead of a script since it is part of a package, so you should run it as a module and not as a script: `python -m autostart.filea`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I guess I need to refactor but this gave me a good idea.